# Are there workarounds for using legacy JWS applications?

Tags: jnlp

In my teaching, I use a java application (http://gcsimulator.org/simulator.php) that has been abandoned and is no longer maintained.  Presently, there are no alternatives that meet my needs and I would like to continue using the software.  I understand that there are multitudes of security issues and that Java Web Start is/will be deprecated.

Is there a way to continue using this application, off line without the JNLP wrapper, with current java versions?  I'd be happy with sandboxed solutions (e.g. running an instance on a Raspberry Pi).  Since I am not the author of the software and the codebase is not available, my only options are to make the legacy application work or give up using this type of tool in my teaching.  (I'd rather avoid the latter option.)

Comment: Did you try to contact Paul? It seems that he wanted to open source it (http://gcsimulator.org/development/index.php). I believe that he is not working at the univercity anymore but now works for Turing Tumble. You can easily find him on linked-in. Explain your situation and ask him for the code. I would then setup a github project and start converting the programm away from jnlp to a standalone java program...

Comment: @Lonzak yes, and I did touch base with his collaborator, who has taken the project in a [different direction](http://www.multidlc.org/hplcsim/hplcsim.html) which is good for the **next** chapter in my course, but not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I took to solve this problem was

- Manually download each jar file mentioned in the JNLP XML *including* any JNLP files referenced therein
- extract the class files all in the same root directory either with WinRAR (Windows) or `jar -xvf` in linux
- call the app from the command line using `java org.gcsimulator.GCSimulatorApp`

I am now able to treat this directory as a portable executable.  I suspect I could simplify things a bit by making a new JAR; however I don't have the java development environment on my computer.

FWIW, this method only created a functional program on my Windows system.  I ended up with an openGL problem at the final stages of the RPi process and chose not to diagnose it further.